# mysql select count with another select count

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

how can i combine these two queries in mysql?

```
 select count(*) as entry_count from tbl_entries where user_id = x
```

and

```
select username, avatar from tbl_users where user_id = x
```

I want one result that combines the result of this 2 queries. Please help me guys!

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select username, 
       avatar,
       (select count(*) from tbl_entries where user_id = x) as entry_count
from tbl_users 
where user_id = x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select username,
       avatar,
       (select count(*) from tbl_entries where user_id = x) AS cnt
  from tbl_users
 where user_id = x
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
SELECT a.username,
        a.avatar,
        COUNT(*) as entry_count,
FROM tbl_Users a LEFT JOIN tbl_entries b ON
        a.user_ID = b.user_ID
WHERE a.user_ID = x
GROUP BY a.username
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT U.username, U.avatar, 
    count(*) AS entry_count 
FROM tbl_users AS U
LEFT JOIN tbl_entries AS E ON U.user_id = E.user_id
WHERE user_id = x
GROUP BY U.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT username, 
       avatar, 
       (select count(*) from tbl_entries where user_id = U.user_id) AS cnt 
 FROM tbl_users AS U
 WHERE user_id = x